# .rec file usage incase if we want to run graph form specific phase

Tags: ab-initio

In abinitio, job has failed in specific phase for example phase 4, and we fixed the issue and rollback the .rec file, if we want to run the graph from phase 4 only, how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can restart a job, and it will continue from the last checkpoint, which in a batch graph is a checkpointed phase break. If the graph failed in phase 4, restarting will continue from the beginning of phase 4, assuming you set checkpointed phases.

Your question is confusing: you said the job failed in phase 4, which means it wouldn't have continued to a later phase. If you mean it didn't fail in phase 4 and it continued to a later phase, but you discovered an error that may have produced incorrect results (such as the wrong data in some input to that phase), unfortunately you're out of luck -- the job will have to be re-run from the beginning.

There's no way to roll back to a previous phase, because that work is already done and committed. The system cleaned up the files etc. that allow restart of the phase when it completed, before setting up and starting the next phase.